# Extend RecyclerView and get clicked item's position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to extend RecyclerView to make certain modifications of my own. This is what I currently have:

```
public class FeedRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    private int currentClickedItem = -1;

    public FeedRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public FeedRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public FeedRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    // Check if item in RecyclerView is clicked
    // If so, update "currentClickedItem" to the correct position

}
```

When a user clicks on an item in the RecyclerView, I want to update the value of `currentClickedItem` in the above code. What method would I use to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It can be done by using the Adapter and an interface why you want a custom Recyclerview for that. Seems like moving in the wrong direction.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela I will use this value later in the RecyclerView to track which items in the RecyclerView are visible on the screen on scroll and compare that to the value of `currentClickedItem`.

Comment: Sorry, i m not able to understand what exactly you wish to achieve. Maybe somebody else will guide/help you.

Comment: I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```java
rv_list.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(activity, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {

                    Toast.makeText(activity, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
    );
```

This gets you the position of the clicked item.

Comment: What is `RecyclerItemClickListener`?